Safari number input field dispatching change event on hover
Minimal reproducible code:
HTML
<input id="myinput" type="number" value="0"/>

<div id='modal' class='hidden'></div>

CSS
#modal {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.hidden { display: none; }

JS
const input = document.getElementById("myinput") 
const modal = document.getElementById('modal')

input.addEventListener('change', (event) => { 
    modal.classList.remove('hidden')

    setTimeout(() => { 
        modal.classList.add('hidden') 
    } , 1000) 
})

On Safari (17.4.1) when clicking increment/decrement arrow in input field, overlay is shown for 1 second. After overlay is hidden, if you move mouse over increment/decrement icons, change event is being sometimes triggered on input element. How to prevent that from happening?
Few things that I have found:

If overlay have pointer-events: none then everything works fine, but that is not acceptable solution since overlay is meant for preventing user for clicking on element below it

Seems like problem is that click event is not triggered in Safari in this situation. If I would delay overlay show until click event is triggered then everything would work correctly. Simply putting my execution code in click event callback is not acceptable solution since I need to trigger that code also on, for example, keyup.

In Chrome everything works fine because click event is being triggered.


EDIT:
Seems like it is specific macOS problem, for example, macOS 12.7.4 wasn't working, but on 14.4.1 and 13.6 was working, seems like regardless on Safari version
